# Why $(this).css doesn't work in ajax success?

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I don't know if $(this) selector work in ajax success or not , here is the code :

```
$(".up_button").click(function(){
    var idup_post=$(this).attr("data-idupactive");
    var userup_post=$(this).attr("data-userupactive");

    $.ajax({
        url:"ajax/up_actv.php",
        data:{"idup":idup_post,"userup":userup_post},
        type:"POST",
        success:function(data){

            if(data=="upactv"){
                alert(data); //just to check if ajax response is correct
        $(this).css({
            "background-image":"url('icons/u.png')"
        });
        }
        if(data=="updisv"){
            alert(data); //just to check if ajax response is correct
    $(this).css({
            "background-image":"url('icons/uf.png')"
        });
        }


        }

    });

});
```

I need to change the background of the selected button , So any help will be welcomed

Comment: this here points to window global object

Comment: well, no, it actually points to something else, but you are correct in that it isn't what the OP expected it to be.

Comment: Have you thought about adding a class instead of calling an image on the object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this here refers to XHR(ajax request) object.

you can change the reference either using call/apply or copy the reference into a variable and use that

check this snippet

```
$(".up_button").click(function() {
  var self = this;
  var idup_post = $(this).attr("data-idupactive");
  var userup_post = $(this).attr("data-userupactive");

  $.ajax({
    url: "ajax/up_actv.php",
    data: {
      "idup": idup_post,
      "userup": userup_post
    },
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {

      if (data == "upactv") {
        alert(data); //just to check if ajax response is correct
        $(self).css({
          "background-image": "url('icons/u.png')"
        });
      }
      if (data == "updisv") {
        alert(data); //just to check if ajax response is correct
        $(self).css({
          "background-image": "url('icons/uf.png')"
        });
      }


    }

  });

});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes sorry about that made the chage

Comment: You are amazing, thank you a lot (y) . I now understand the problem

Comment: the problem is you are trying to set css to the this object...where this is referring to the window/global object.so just copy the reference of this to a variable outside of the request and access that variable within success function and try to apply css to it

Answer (score 3):

Because `this` in `success(..)` function is pointing to a different thing then a button (usually the **[jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)** object) .
To access button in `success(..)` you could save its reference beforehand :

```
$(".up_button").click(function(){
  var idup_post=$(this).attr("data-idupactive");
  var userup_post=$(this).attr("data-userupactive");
  var button = this;
  :
  :
  success : function(data) {
     :
     $(button).css(..);
  }
```

or better yet assign the button as the `ajax(..)` context:

```
$(".up_button").click(function() {
  var idup_post = $(this).attr("data-idupactive");
  var userup_post = $(this).attr("data-userupactive");

  $.ajax({
    context: this,  // 'this' refers to button
    :
    success: function(data) {
      // now `this` refers to the value of `context`
    } 
});
```

See the **context** section of jQuery Ajax [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

'this' now represent the ajax request you can use this code

```
$(".up_button").click(function(){
var idup_post=$(this).attr("data-idupactive");
var userup_post=$(this).attr("data-userupactive");

var up_btn = $(this); // put the button object inside var

$.ajax({
    url:"ajax/up_actv.php",
    data:{"idup":idup_post,"userup":userup_post},
    type:"POST",
    success:function(data){

        if(data=="upactv"){
            alert(data); 
            up_btn.css({ // use the var insted of 'this'
                "background-image":"url('icons/u.png')"
            });
         }
        if(data=="updisv"){
            alert(data); 
            up_btn.css({ // same thing
                "background-image":"url('icons/uf.png')"
            });
         }


    }

});

});
```